# I'm trying to override a method that returns a different Class depending on different circumstances. What is the elegant way to do so?

Tags: java, class, constructor

My current code is as follows:

```
public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
    switch (columnIndex) {
        case 0:
            class = Integer.class;
            break;

        case 1:
            class = String.class;
            break;

        case 2:
            class = ArrayList.class;
            break;
    }

    return class;
}
```

Now, the problem is that I can not create that class object because `Class` has no public constructor. So the only alternative I can think of is using a different return sentence in each case, which I've always been told is a no-no. Is there any alternative I'm missing?

Comment: This isn't clear. If you're trying to return a `Class`, then you're code already works. If you're trying to return an *instance of a particular class*, then this isn't correct at all.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth it doesn't work because the class variable I am returning can't be constructed, there is no public constructor for that.

Comment: Why do you need to construct a `Class`?

Comment: That doesn't make sense. `Integer.class` (for example) is an object, it's already constructed.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth how would you create the object that stores the value then? something like Class class=null; just doesn't work, you can try it yourself if you don't believe me. The [api](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) says "Class has no public constructor. Instead Class objects are constructed automatically by the Java Virtual Machine as classes are loaded and by calls to the defineClass method in the class loader."

Comment: `class` is a reserved keyword, use something else in your switch/case

Comment: Also, even if it weren't a reserved word, you can't assign a variable you haven't declared.

Comment: @kace91 You need to appreciate the difference between declaration and construction. A declaration like `Class x = null;` has nothing to do with construction.

Comment: @ChrisMartin then why doesn't the code work for me? I'm not trying to argue against your comment, I'm just trying to understand why everyone accepts Class x = null; as correct but I can't even compile it.

Comment: you can't compile when it's called x?

Comment: @ChrisMartin forget about it, sorry. As I commented in other reply, it was just a really dumb error on my part: I didn't see that I had mistakenly put the declaration line inside the switch clause, instead of just before it. I'm sorry to waste your time, it's embarrasing :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can correct your code as following. But I am not sure what are you trying to do here.

```
 public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
 Class cls=null;// don't use Class class since class is a key word in Java
    switch (columnIndex) {
        case 0:
            cls = Integer.class;
            break;
        case 1:
            cls = String.class;
            break;
        case 2:
            cls = ArrayList.class;
            break;
    }
    return cls; 
}
```

Comment: That was my first idea, but the thing is, Class cls=null; is not valid. You can not construct a Class object, hence my question.

Comment: Other than lack of typos, how is that different to the OP's code?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth can't you see any difference. OP code not even compile.

Comment: @kace91 `Class cls=null` is valid. You can use some default class if you don't want to initialize it as `null`

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera then why can't I compile it? (honest question). I don't understand why it seeems to work for everyone here but me.

Comment: @kace91 compile which one?

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera your corrected version. Or any other that involves declaring a Class. The line Class cls=null; won't work, although, for example, Class<Integer> cls =null; does work (but of course, I don't want to specify it).

Comment: @kace91 what do you mean by won't work. Just look at this please.http://ideone.com/RgVSHh

Comment: Oh god. I feel retarded. All this time I was getting an error in that line  because I missed that I had placed it _inside_ the switch clause by mistake. My apologies man, I'm sorry for making you waste your time with this.

Answer (score 0):

So, um, there's a lot of confusion in this question. But, if what you've written does what it's supposed to, and you just want a better way to express it, I'd recommend something like this.

```
static Class[] COLUMN_CLASSES =
    {Integer.class, String.class, ArrayList.class};
public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
    return COLUMN_CLASSES[columnIndex];
}
```